# How to implement sliding navigation menu and iAd together in xcode?

Tags: iad, submenu

Iam trying to implement a sliding menu using the JWSlideMenu project off of github and a bannerView Controller together. Both of these codes want to be the root view controller in AppDelegate.m but i can only implement one? Is any way around this?

Example

```
self.window.rootViewController = slideMenu;
```

or

```
 self.window.rootViewController = _bannerViewController;
```

Any help would be appreciated.